# Databricks %sql - Copy into by selecting columns to upload

Tags: sql, github, copy, databricks, databricks-sql

I am trying to copy the table DimAccount (saved as .csv) from Adventureworks into my table tmpAccount in databricks. Instead of uploading all 9 columns I would like to copy only 4 columns. Unfortunaty my commands are wrong.

Can anyone help me here?

```
%sql

create schema AdventureWorks;
```

then

```
%sql

create table AdventureWorks.tmpAccount (
  AccountKey int,                             -- 1
  AccountCodeAlternateKey int,                -- 3
  AccountDescription string,                  -- 5
  AccountType string                          -- 6
);
```

and finally

```
%sql 
copy into AdventureWorks.tmpAccount
from
  (select p.$1, p.$3, p.$5, p.$6
  from "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/anotherrepo/myrepo/main/data/Account.csv" p
  )
fileformat = CSV
format_options ('header' = 'true')
```

Here is the error:

[image: PARSE_SYNTAX_ERROR]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use real column names, not the `$<number>` syntax, especially if you have `header = true` - then column names will come from the file itself. Also, you need to have file on the cloud service (S3/ADLS/...), not as HTTP URL. See [doc for details](https://docs.databricks.com/ingestion/copy-into/examples.html).

Comment: Thanks. I follow the documentation as instructed and is working now.. But since I don't have a cloud account (working with Community Edition) I ended up cp from github to dbfs and then loading from there!
But, why can I cp from https url but not in copy into from?

Comment: that's are different sources.